# how to accurately count unique instances of an object open cv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an OpenCV python application where I need I need to count the unique occurrences of the detected object(s).

I have tried to track the occurrence of the bounding boxes, but it looks like it keeps resetting every time and not adding up the total number of times the object is detected.

Here is the console output:

```
Palm Trees: 0
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 6
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 5
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 2
Palm Trees: 2
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 2
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 5
Palm Trees: 4
Palm Trees: 3
Palm Trees: 3
```

Here is my python code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov3_training_last.weights', 'yolov3_testing.cfg')

classes = []
with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    classes = f.read().splitlines()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('driveday2_plamtrees.mp4')
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(100, 3))

a=[]
count_trees = 0;

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    height, width, _ = img.shape

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1/255, (416, 416), (0,0,0), swapRB=True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    output_layers_names = net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames()
    layerOutputs = net.forward(output_layers_names)

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    class_ids = []

    for output in layerOutputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.2:
                center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                center_y = int(detection[1]*height)
                w = int(detection[2]*width)
                h = int(detection[3]*height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                a.append([center_x,center_y])
                # print("Palm Trees: " + str(len(a)))
                confidences.append((float(confidence)))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.2, 0.4)

    if len(indexes)>0:
        for i in indexes.flatten():
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            confidence = str(round(confidences[i],2))
            color = colors[i]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 2)
            cv2.putText(img, label + " " + confidence, (x, y+20), font, 2, (255,255,255), 1)
            count_trees = 1 + len(boxes)
    print("Palm Trees: " + str(count_trees))

    cv2.imshow('Image', img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I accurately count the number of times the object is uniquely detected?

Comment: You do reset the list of boxes in the while True loop, so you need a counter that’s reset outside the loop and incremented inside

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Can you show me in my code where I should fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you should just change

```
count_trees = 1 + len(boxes)
```

to

```
count_trees += 1 + len(boxes)
```

so you keep adding the number of boxes to the total.

Edit:
The algorithm seem to count the boxes several times, so another strategy must be used:
Keep track of each x,y-pair as set of tuples, and count these. This will still count too many, if the detection rectangles slightly overlap for the same palm. In that case one must only add a new tuple to the set, if it is different by some tolerance. The tolerance value should depend on how close the palms are spaced

Comment: it appears to be counting every time a detection box is drawn - even on the same tree already detected.

Comment: In that case, the best strategy must be to keep track of each x,y-pair as  set of tuples, and count these. This will still count too many, if the detection rectangles slightly overlap for the same palm. Maybe only add a new tuple to the set, if it is different by some amount?

Comment: Stefan -- that seems to be a sound approach.
Let me see what I can do for that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Stefan's, to verify if you accumulated unique count of palm trees correctly, add this line before `cap.release()`

```
print(f"Total palm tree count -- {count_trees}")
```